# How can we verify response data schema(column values only) in jmeter?

Tags: api, jmeter, assertion

I need to verify API schema in jmeter.
My API response data is

```
[{
    "snid": "1",
    "subject": "Automation",
    "state": null,
    "country": null,
    "contact_name": "John",
    "email": "John@gmail.com",
    "phone": "402-221-9999"
}, {
    "snid": "2",
    "subject": "Testing",
    "state": null,
    "country": null,
    "contact_name": "Smith",
    "email": "jmstauch@leoadaly.com",
    "phone": "402-111-2222"
}]
```

so I want to verify that it contains the response message as

```
{
    "snid": "",
    "subject": "",
    "state": ,
    "country": ,
    "contact_name": "",
    "email": "",
    "phone": ""
}
```

I just need to verify the columns name and ordering of the fields.
I have used `response assertions` contains but it doesn't verify the order, also `JSON path assertion` verify the object values not the parameter(or it verify the complete message) but in my case I need to verify the exact schema.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a work around that you
first parse the object as json slurper

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper();

def response = slurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());

def testdata = response[0].keySet() as List;
```

this will save testdata as

[ "snid","subject","state","country","contact_name","email","phone"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map.keySet()`, it will give you all the keys from the map.

```
[ "snid",
  "subject",
  "state",
  "country",
  "contact_name",
  "email",
  "phone"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) and i.e. [Groovy JSON Schema](https://github.com/alexdeleon/groovy-json-schema) for this as currently there are no relevant bundled test elements and/or plugins to cover this functionality. Make sure you have the .jar in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

See [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information on using Groovy scripting in JMeter.